# Can "this" announce a date?

Tags: pronouns, dates

Practical English Usage section 323 has

> To announce the date, It's is used.
>
> It's April (the) first.

Can I use "this/that" to announce a date?

I'm talking with my friend about my summer part-time job. My friend may not know when my summer vacation is, so I need to emphasize now is the beginning of my summer vacation.

**This is the beginning of my summer vacation, and I haven't found a part-time job.**

Or how about

**This is at the beginning of my summer vacation ...**

Comment: _The beginning of my summer vacation_ isn't a date, it's just a phrase describing what the day means to you. You could use **This is the...** or **Today is the...**

Comment: My wife: Let's go to Salisbury next Monday. Me: That's the start of the school holidays.